# Let $0$ and $\infty$ are both essential singularity of $f$. How can I prove that $\,\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\frac{\log A(r)}{\log r}=\infty\,?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$, with essential singularity at $0$ and $\infty.$

Let $\,A(r)=\mathop{\text{max}}\limits_{|z|=r}\text{Re}f(z)\,,\;\;0<r<\infty$. Please prove that
$$\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\frac{\log A(r)}{\log r}=\infty\,,$$
$$\lim\limits_{r\to0}\frac{\log A(r)}{\log\frac1r}=\infty\,.$$

There’s a similar question maybe helpful here:

Suppose an entire function $\,h\,$ is not a polynomial (It means $\,h\,$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$). Set $\,M(r)=\max\limits_{|z|=r}|h(z)|\,$. Then I can use contradiction to show that for any positive integer $\,k\,$, we have
$$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{M(r)}{r^k}=+\infty\,.$$

I’m wondering could we transform $\,f\,$ in the original question in some way. For example, subtract its principal part at singularity $0$ from $\,f\,$, and then it may perform like an entire function. Or could we consider the function $\,g(z):=e^{f(z)}\,$, and then use $\,|g(z)|\,$ to study the behavior of $\,\text{Re}f(z)$ ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The real part is harmonic, so by maximum principle we can consider the maximum over a punctured ball of radius of $r$ centered at the origin. This in particular shows $A(r)$ is monotonic. Picard's theorem then shows we can find a sequence of points approaching $\infty$ where $f$ takes arbitrarily large values in $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$. The growth at infinity must in fact be super-polynomial, else we would have a meromorphic function there. Some combination of these facts should combine together to give what you want

Comment: It is enough to prove the result at zero (using $z \to 1/z$) so assume by contradiction $\frac{\log A(r)}{\log\frac1r} \le M$ and deduce that $A(r) \le C/r^n, r<1$ say and then deduce that since $z^{n+1}A(z) \to 0, |z| \to 0$ is bounded, that $z^{n+1}B(z)$, where $f(z)=A(z)+iB(z)$, is bounded, so $f(z)$ has at most a pole at $0$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks! I understand the thought of your comment, but I still can not prove that.

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for your comment, but I don’t know how “$A(r)$”  became “$A(z)$” .

Comment: Call $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ and then show that $z^{n+1}u(z) \to 0$ implies that $f$ has a pole at zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me indicate how to prove the result using Borel Caratheodory for example; since $f$ is analytic on the plane minus the origin, it can be written as $f(z)=\sum_{ n \in \mathbb Z}a_n z^n =F(z)+G(z)$ where $F(z)=\sum_{ n \ge 0}a_n z^n$ is entire and $G(z)=\sum_{ n \le -1}a_n z^n$ is entire in $w=1/z$ - in other words, $H(w)=\sum_{ n \ge 1}a_{-n} w^n$ is entire and $H(0)=0$.

Now let $G(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ and note that for $|z| \le 1$ we have that $|\Re f(z)-u(z)|=|\Re F(z)| \le C$ since $F$ is analytic on the unit disc, so if we assume by contradiction that $\frac{\log A(r)}{\log\frac1r} \le K$ for $0<r<1/2$, then we get that with $\,A_{G}(r)=\mathop{\text{max}}\limits_{|z|=r}\text{Re}G(z)\,,\;\;0<r<\infty$, we also have $\frac{\log A_G(r)}{\log\frac1r} \le N, r<1/2$ for some $N$ which we can take to be a positive integer, so we get that $r^N A_G(r) \le C, 0<r<1/2$.

But now it's clear that $A_H(r)=A_G(1/r)$ so we get $ A_H(r)/r^N \le C, r>2$ and then from Borel Caratheodory we get that $M_H(r)=\sup_{|z|=r}|H(z)|$ satisfies $M_H(r) \le 2A_H(2r)$ (since $H(0)=0$) which means that $ M_H(r)/r^N \le C_1, r>2$ which means by usual considerations (eg Cauchy, or integrating the square modulus on large circles etc) that $H$ is a polynomial of degree at most $N$, or that $G$ has a pole of order at most $N$ at $0$ or $f$ same and we get the required contradiction.

For the $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\frac{\log A(r)}{\log r}=\infty\,$ part we just take $g(z)=f(1/z)$ and apply the above result to $g$

Comment: I think your method is considering the principal part of the Laurent series of $f$ at $0$ , and then use $w=1/z$ to make it an analytic function in a disc . Finally,use Caratheodory Inequality to estimate the real part “Re” by the modulus, which deduce a contradiction. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes - the Borel caratheodory theorem is the link between the real part and the modulus and here one needs to apply it carefully to the situation